# how would you make it so that it grabs a random number and uses it to grab objects from an array

Tags: javascript, html

I have some code but it doesn't work, and instead of displaying a random object from the array, it displays the random number used to try display an object

```html
<html>

    <body>

    <h1>HTML random objects</h1>

    <p>makes a random object get displayed on the screen (but it doesn't because it doesn't work)</p>

    <button onclick="objects[random()]">Click Me</button>
    <p id="rand"></p>
    <script>
    var objects = ["house", "bee", "car"];
    function random(){
        document.getElementById("rand").innerHTML = 
Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    }
    </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("rand").innerHTML = objects[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];` - and `onclick="random()"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track, just needed to call the objects array with the random number, like this: `objects[randomNumber]`

```html
<h1>HTML random objects</h1>
<p>makes a random object get displayed on the screen (but it doesn't because it doesn't work)</p>

<button onclick="objects[random()]">Click Me</button>
<p id="rand"></p>

<script>
  var objects = ["house", "bee", "car"];
  function random(){
    document.getElementById("rand").innerHTML = objects[Math.floor(Math.random() * objects.length)];
  }
</script>
```

Comment: ok, thanks, I can see the problem and probably put this into future projects!! thanks!